# Is it possible to see all the requests processed by redis?

Tags: redis, jedis, redis-cli

I want to get all the commands processed by redis without using `MONITOR` command because `MONITOR` command is used to get info of all commands at present.But this is not my case.I want to know the commands processed for last 2 days.Is it possible to see the last 2 days commands processed by redis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. You might be able to get close if you have AOF persistence enabled and it hasn't been rewritten during that time.